# How should I fix a failed kexec that produces "CPUs are stuck in the kernel" in dmesg?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kexec

I have built both a kernel from the Raspberry Pi sources and kexec-tools for arm64, and booted my kernel on a Raspberry Pi 4.

When I attempt to run kexec, it produces no output, exits with a nonzero return code, and an error message is posted to dmesg.

### The debug output

While running kexec normally prints no output, running with `--debug` to show debug messages shows:

```bsh
# kexec -s -l /media/sda1/boot/vmlinuz-rpi4barb --initrd /media/sda1/boot/initramfs-rpi4barb --reuse-cmdline --debug
arch_process_options:178: command_line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:09:35:A1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3eb00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3ff00000  modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod,usb-storage quiet console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200
arch_process_options:180: initrd: /media/sda1/boot/initramfs-rpi4barb
arch_process_options:182: dtb: (null)
arch_process_options:185: console: (null)
Try gzip decompression.
Try LZMA decompression.
lzma_decompress_file: read on /media/sda1/boot/vmlinuz-rpi4barb of 65536 bytes failed
elf_arm64_probe: Not an ELF executable.

# echo $?
255
```

My kernel *did* boot (so it must be *some* kind of executable). `file` claims:

```bsh
# file /media/sda1/boot/vmlinuz-rpi4barb
/media/sda1/boot/vmlinuz-rpi4barb: Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image, little-endian, 4K pages
```

### The dmesg output

When I run `kexec`, the line `Can't kexec: CPUs are stuck in the kernel` appears in dmesg.

What does it mean that `CPUs are stuck in the kernel`, and what should I do to resolve this problem? I have googled the message, and found mostly the code that generates it and a few unanswered questions.

### Is this related to PSCI?

[One mailing list thread](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/kexec/2017-April/018569.html) which did have some replies indicated the problem may lie with something called [PSCI](https://linux-sunxi.org/PSCI). Running the suggested command `dmesg | grep -E 'psci|started in'` results in no output, indicating that PSCI is not supported in the kernel that I built.

I don't understand that answer. The kernel docs [place PSCI under kvm](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/virt/kvm/arm/psci.html), but my kernel is booting to physical hardware.

Am I missing something?

### Any help greatly appreciated

Have I built my kernel wrong? Are there any docs or posts I've missed showing the right way to do this?

Thanks for looking.